# The service "admin.category" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sonata.admin.manager.orm"

Tags: symfony, sonata

To set up Sonata admin in Symfony 3, I followed the exact instructions:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.x/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/getting_started/creating_an_admin.html

At step 3, I have entered the exact configuration as described:
https://symfony.com/doc/3.x/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/getting_started/creating_an_admin.html#step-3-register-the-admin-class

```
services:
    # ...
    admin.category:
        class: App\Admin\CategoryAdmin
        arguments: [~, App\Entity\Category, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Category }
```

But now I get the following error:

```
The service "admin.category" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sonata.admin.manager.orm".
```

Comment: Did you install `SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle` ?

Answer (score 8):

just run :

```html
composer require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle
```